# Using combobox(using databound items) to populate listbox

Tags: c#

How do I populate a listbox using select query (which stems from a combobox, data bound items)

If 'multi ice cream' is selected in the combobox then I want the system to select that row and show me what is in the 'process' column in my listbox

At the moment, the software is returning all rows under that column

```
MAcon.Open();
 OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Product Family] Where Process = @Process", MAcon);
 da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Process", ItemCBx.Text);
 DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dtbl);
 if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
 {
     Listbox1.Text.ToString().Split(',').ToList().ForEach(c => Listbox1.Items.Add(c.Trim()));
     Define.SelectedIndex = 1;
 }

MAcon.Close();
```

Comment: What is the question exactly ?

Comment: How do I display the items in a cell in a listbox - using a combobox which uses data bound items

Comment: You want to populate the comoboBox with whatever the query returns ?

Comment: I want to populate a listbox with whatever the query returns

Comment: It is returning all of the rows in the database, rather than just one row under that column

Comment: So, if i understood you correctly, based on what the user select from the comboBox, you make a query and fill the ListBox with the result, Correct?

Comment: yes, thats what I want to happen

Comment: Where is this code being used?  What event? Avoid using the "Text" property of a combo box. You want the SelectedItem or SelectedValue depending on how it is setup.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an eventHandler for when the user selects something in the comboBox.

Then get the selectedItem like `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` and pass it to the query.

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Process",comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Then

```
if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
 {
     // Selects the value located in teh first row and first columns
     // if that is what your query is returning
     listBox1.Items.Add(dtbl.Rows[0][0]); 
 }
```

Problem : i don't know what your query returns see that `*` means it will return multiple columns and you can only have one element per line in listbox, i would suggest having a dataGridView control and `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` and it will display all the returned columns.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it more now. But now the listbox is just empty